# vbox: splittable aligned equations? measuring true height after vsplit

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, boxes, plain-tex

I am learning low-level tex to write my own custom *latex macros. As an experiment I tried to put math equations (multiline or not) inside `\vbox`/ `\hbox`, measure their dimensions, and tried to split multiline aligned equations inside `\vbox` using `\vsplit` using package `amsmath`'s `align` environment. From the behavior of split, it seems like `align` environment returns a `hbox` to be put in surrounding vertical list? How could one get aligned equations to split? I don't care if we use `align` environment or some plain-tex equivalent, it would be nice to be able to split aligned math equations. Unfortunately plain tex's `\eqlign`, and `$$` does not work in *latex, so I did not test what does it do (whether it returns multiline equations wrapped in a `\hbox`, or not).

Two other observations (for corresponding `NOTE-num`'s inside the code): 1) `NOTE-1` If I do not  set `*displayskip` to `0pt`, the height of vsplit is 10pt shorter than original `vbox`, why this difference in measurement? 2) `NOTE-2` If I do not `\unvcopy` the contents of split back into the split, then the reported height of split is 12pt (=1\baselineskip) instead of the height of original contents. Is this expected behavior? Do I always need to do this right after split to make it report the correct height of contents?

Here's my code (run with `>> lualatex test.tex`):

```
% lualatex test.tex
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

% NOTE-1: If I comment this, then there is a 10pt difference in height of split, and height of vbox contaning same math
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myformula}{%
\begin{align*}%
x^2+y^2 &= z^2\\%
a^2+b^2+1 &= c^3\\%
\end{align*}%
}

********* test math in vbox ************\\

\newbox\mymathvbox
\global\setbox\mymathvbox=\vbox{{\myformula\endgraf}}

mymathvbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathvbox, dp \the\dp\mymathvbox.

\copy\mymathvbox

mymathvbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathvbox, dp \the\dp\mymathvbox\\

********** test math in hbox ***********\\

\newbox\mymathhbox
\setbox\mymathhbox=\hbox{\copy\mymathvbox}

mymathhbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathhbox, dp \the\dp\mymathhbox

\copy\mymathhbox

mymathhbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathhbox, dp \the\dp\mymathhbox\\

************ test vbox split *********\\

\newbox\mymathvboxsplit
\setbox\mymathvboxsplit=\vsplit\mymathvbox to 1\baselineskip
% NOTE-2: If I comment the following line, then reported ht of split is 12pt (=1\baselineskip)
\setbox\mymathvboxsplit=\vbox{\unvcopy\mymathvboxsplit}

mymathvbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathvbox, dp \the\dp\mymathvbox; mymathvboxsplit dimen:  ht \the\ht\mymathvboxsplit, dp \the\dp\mymathvboxsplit


\copy\mymathvbox

\copy\mymathvboxsplit

mymathvbox dimen: ht \the\ht\mymathvbox, dp \the\dp\mymathvbox; mymathvboxsplit dimen:  ht \the\ht\mymathvboxsplit, dp \the\dp\mymathvboxsplit

\end{document}
```

Screenshot without commenting the code mentioned in `NOTE-1` and `NOTE-2`: Commenting code below `NOTE-1` would show 10pt discrepancy in dimensions of mymathvbox, and mymathvboxsplit. Then commenting line below `NOTE-2` will show that the height of contents of mymathvboxsplit changes to size specified in split (12pt) instead of height of material within it.

[image: without commenting code below note1 and note2]

Comment: align returns a vertical list that can split but by default has nobreak penalties between each line, use `\allowdisplaybreaks` so the penalty allows splitting.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks I just tested that and splitting (`vsplit`) on aligned equations from `align` environment worked. Any insight on height measurement questions from two `NOTE`s?

Comment: no time to debug your code now but vsplit is like a page break and discards discardable items after the split (and adds space at the top of the second part based on \spilttopskip) then adjusts depths depending on `\splitmaxdepth`, so you wouldn't expect the sum of the split parts to add up to the original size.

Comment: You might benefit from the fact that `amsmath` was converted from AMS-TeX, which was written for plain TeX.  An [archive of AMS-TeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/amstex) is present on CTAN, including a pdf copy of *Joy of TeX* and a file of the author's comments about the code.